# Using ManagementScope in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wmi

I'm trying to connect and modify the dns server using asp.net mvc application.
when executing following code, I get an error:

```
    private void Logon()
    {
        _namespace = "\\\\" + _serverName + "\\root\\microsoftdns";

        var con = new ConnectionOptions
                      {
                          Username = _userName,
                          Password = _password,
                          Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
                      };
        _managementScope = new ManagementScope(_namespace)
                               {
                                   Options = con
                               };
        _managementScope.Connect();
    }
```

and the error is:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>   To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

How should I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the identity that the site is running under and make sure that the identity has permissions to make the changes